# Git Orphan branch "This branch is 1 commit ahead, n commits behind master"

Tags: git, github, orphaned-objects

I've used the following to create an *orphan* branch on a local repo, then pushed it to a remote on Github:

```
git checkout --orphan worker
git rm -rf .
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial orphan commit"
git push origin worker
```

I get the *"This branch is 1 commit ahead, n commits behind master"* message while on the *worker* branch on GitHub.

The idea here is to create an *empty, unrelated*  branch with no history, totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits and, that isn't tracked in relation to the master branch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've done so. GitHub's message is basically meaningless in this case. Your branch has 1 commit that isn't in master, and master has n commits that aren't in your branch. GitHub should probably suppress that message when there is no common ancestor, but it looks like it doesn't :)

Comment: GitHub really should suppress the message because it gives the impression that the orphan branch is still being tracked in relation to _master_. +1 for clarifying that it isn't.